# Symfony Can't export data to Excel

Tags: excel, symfony

hello everyone im using Liuggio Excel Bundle but cant make it work :/ i added and option above my list of users to export the data to excel but when is clicked nothing happens, no download.
could somebody give me a hand?

maybe im calling it wrong?? or its working but i dont know where it save the file?? 
this is how i call the method.

```
<a href="{{ path('excel_list') }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Export Data</a>
```

routing:

```
excel_list:
path:     /excel_list
defaults: { _controller: PaginasUsersBundle:Default:ExcelExport }
```

here is the method of my controller:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------Excel--------------------------
//----------------------------------------------------------

public function ExcelExportAction(Request $request)
{
$em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$query=$em->getRepository('PaginasUsersBundle:Users')
    ->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->select('u.id, u.name, u.username, u.email')
    ->getQuery();

$result=$filterQuery->getResult();

$phpExcelObject = $this->get('phpexcel')->createPHPExcelObject();

$phpExcelObject->getProperties()
    ->setCreator("xxx")
    ->setLastModifiedBy("xxxx")
    ->setTitle("Excel Example")
    ->setSubject("Example")
    ->setDescription("Example List");

$phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$phpExcelObject->getActiveSheet()->setTile('Export Example');

$phpExcelObject->setACtiveSheetIndex(0)
    ->setCellValue('B2','ID')
    ->setCellValue('C2','Name')
    ->setCellValue('D2','Username')
    ->setCellValue('E2','Email');

//fijamos un ancho a las distintas columnas
$phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
    ->getColumnDimension('B')
    ->setWidth(30);
$phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
    ->getColumnDimension('C')
    ->setWidth(25);
$phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
    ->getColumnDimension('D')
    ->setWidth(15);
$phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
    ->getColumnDimension('E')
    ->setWidth(20);

$row=3;
foreach ($result as $item){
    $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('B'.$row, $item['id'])
        ->setCellValue('C'.$row, $item['name'])
        ->setCellValue('D'.$row, $item['username'])
        ->setCellValue('E'.$row, $item['email']);
    $row ++;
}

$writer = $this->get('phpexcel')->createWriter($phpObject, 'Excel5');

$response = $this->get('phpexcel')->createStreamedREsponse($writer);

$dispositionHeader = $response->headers->makeDisposition(
    ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
    'userList.xls'
);

$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
$response->headers->set('Pragma', 'public');
$response->headers->set('Cache-control','maxage=1');
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $dispositionHeader);

return $response;

}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What do log files say?

Comment: probably you must replace the object access with array access as example you need to replace this: `$item->getId()` with `$item['id]`

Comment: thanks i updated my Action but still no excel file to download :/

Comment: log file says Channel: request Message: Matched route "user_list". Context:{"route_parameters": {"__constroller":"Paginas\\UsersBundle\\Controller\\DefaultController:listAction", "__route": "user_list"}."request_url": "http://localhost:8000/user_list"}

Comment: `user_list` != `excel_list` ... what does the log contain when you access `excel_list`?

Comment: @ClickLabs when i write on the browser excel_list it shows nothing, just an empty page, the button on the user list should generate an excel to download but it doesnt do anything just reload the user_list page

Answer (score 2):

i already solved it, it was so simple but here is the answer if anyone have the same problem..

just need to save the excel, i was generating the excel but never saving it haha, so i added this line:

```
$writer->save('/path/to/save/filename.xls');
```

thanks to all for your help :)